# B2C- How to access the element of a custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Is there a way to access the element of the custom policy to modify for example the label, the appearance of the controls, color, font, or adding a line...?

[my custom policy interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqWl2.png)

Answer (score 1):

To change labels that AAD B2C generates, you need to customise the language:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

To change the HTML (appearance of the controls, color, font etc)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy